# Change button url when user clicks depending on selected variables

Tags: html, forms

what i have is a url like this:
https://www.someurl/es/search/variable1/variable2/variable3/variable4/variable5/variable6/

I need to have a button that when a user clicks takes him to this url but with variables changed depending on what he has chosed in the select fields. So the variables must be populated from select fields before clicking the button.

Many thanks

Comment: welcome to SO. Thanks for your question but we can help you if you show us some code you have written and where do you get stuck at. Take a minute to take the site tour and learn how to post good questions. Take note that we won't write code for you.

Comment: Yes please show some code

Comment: Where is the question?

Comment: the proble is that i searched over the internet for an answer to this and i have no idear on how to do it :(